# Is it possible to Use git filter-branch with --tree-filter and --subdirectory-filter in a single operation

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I want to rewrite a git repo:

```
\Old-Repo
    \.git
    \old
        \path1
            |-content to migrate
        \path2
            |-unwanted 

\New-Repo
    \.git
        \src
            |-content to migrate
```

- Take content only from old\path [use `subdirectory-filter`]
- Write it in new repo in \src, not \path [use `tree-filter` for moving]

Is it possible to do this in a single filter-branch invocation? I get the desired result when I do 2 separate calls to `filter-branch`  in the order above - when I try to specify `--subdirectory-filter` and `--tree-filter` simultaneously, the move operation `--tree-filter 'mkdir -p C:/tmp; mv * C:/tmp; mkdir src; mv C:/tmp/* src/'` is not done at the end, so the folders also remain at the root of the rewritten repo.

I want to specify that git should apply the subdirectory-filter first, and then the tree-filter, is that possible?

Comment: The two operations *are* done in that order. See [the shell script that implements filter-branch](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a6c0f10a70a6eb101c213b09ae82a9cad252743/git-filter-branch.sh#L371-L396). It's not clear what's going wrong here.

Comment: The command I am running is:
`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mkdir -p C:/tmp; mv * C:/tmp; mkdir src; mv C:/tmp/* src/' --tag-name-filter cat --subdirectory-filter root/old/path1 --prune-empty -- --all`

Comment: To diagnose the problem, either have your tree-filter log what it sees, or hack up a variant of `git filter-branch` that prints commands as it runs them (simplest is to just add `-x` to the shell options, though this will be quite verbose).